# Datastore query splitting behaviour when specifying limit on Dataflow pipeline

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow

I realized that while using the `ReadFromDatastore` PTransform, if the query has a limit set, the query won't be split across workers. The documentation for the Python class says:

"... when the `query` is configured with a `limit` ..., then all the returned results will be read by a single worker in order to ensure correct data. Since data is read from a single worker, this could have **significant impact on the performance of the job**."

In my case, I need to specify the limit, because there are many more entities matching the query in Datastore than I need for this job. However, the performance hit is severe enough that specifying a limit doesn't give me results any faster (or fast enough). What can I do to somehow finish the job and flush the pipeline when I have processed a certain number of entities without getting a performance hit?

Comment: Solved problem by moving the data to BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You could omit limit and filter by something else (date?) and then do top N on Dataflow instead.

Comment: I wasn't able to find `combiners.Top` transforms for some reason, so I was assuming they hadn't been implemented yet. In any case, I just found them. Thanks.

Comment: However, if I had 10 million entities and I only needed 1 million, wouldn't that make the workers still read all 10 million and filter the 1 million afterwards? I suppose I wouldn't be able to narrow down the 10 million before then, since specifying inequality filters would have the same effect as specifying a limit.

Comment: Correct -- that's where pushing down the filtering to Datastore (say, by date or something) could help.

Comment: Specifying a date range would require an inequality filter though and those are also not split the same way queries with a limit aren't. That brings me back to where I began.